# EF Core - InvalidOperationException (Union)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

EF Core 6,

My Users have an Search Form where they can either search per AND or OR. This form has one "searchTerm" Text Field and multiple Checkboxes and Dropdowns.
My problem is now that after the AND worked without problems the OR somehow always throws this Error and I don´t understand why. Apparently it has something to do with the Classtype or what I input, but when I only use that certain Selection it works.

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Order>()
.Union(DbSet<Order>()
    .Where(x => x.OrderId.ToString() == __searchModel_SearchTerm_0 || x.Title.Contains(__searchModel_SearchTerm_0) || x.Description.Contains(__searchModel_SearchTerm_0)))
.Union(EnumerableQuery<Order> {  })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Code:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Order> SearchOrders_OR(SearchModel searchModel)
{
    var orders= context.Orders.AsQueryable();

    var  result = orders
        .Union(context.Orders.Where(x =>
                                x.OrderId.ToString() == searchModel.searchTerm||
                                x.Title.Contains(searchModel.searchTerm) ||
                                x.Description.Contains(searchModel.searchTerm)))
        .Union(context.Orders.WhereIf(x => x.HandleId == searchModel.Handle, () => searchModel.Handle!= 0))
        .Union(context.Orders.WhereIf(x => x.ProjectId == 
                searchModel.Project, () => searchModel.Project != 0))
        .Union..............//many more of the same stuff with WhereIf
        .ToList();

    result = result.OrderBy(y => y.Creation).ToList(); 
    result = result.Take(64).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Func<bool> validation)
{
    return validation?.Invoke() == true ? query.Where(predicate) : Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

First I had the searchTerm in a own if, but I thought that I might fix the error when I put it together with the rest.

What exactly cannot be translated in this Query? I have the exact same query in my AND, just with a different classtype. And I have played around with ToList(), AsQuerable(), etc.

Comment: Problem with `Union` operator. EF Core cannot translate it effectively. Just use `PredicateBuilder` and forgot about `Union`.

Comment: Ohh that one looks interesting!
What do I do with the values that are null or 0, because the User did not fill them? Using dozens of if´s? Ah.. I can just .... .Or(x=>x.OrderId.ToString()...... && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.SearchTerm) , no?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Or` it is the same as `Union`.

Comment: Which package do you mean, btw. Binbin.Linq ?

Comment: [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder) have introduced `PredicateBuilder`.

Comment: Also apply `Take()` before `ToList()`.